# $f$ Lipschitz implies $\max_{y\in K}f(x,y)$ Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $K$ be a compact metric space and $f:K\times K\to \mathbb{R}$ a Lipschitz function. Is it true that the function $g:K\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=\max_{y\in K}f(x,y)$ is Lipschitz ?

Edit:
What I tried was the following : define, for every $x\in K$, $h(x)$ to be any element of $K$ with $g(x)=f(x,h(x))$. Then 
\begin{align*}
g(x_1)-g(x_2) &=f(x_1, h(x_1))-f(x_2, h(x_2))\\&\leq L\cdot( d(x,y)+d(h(x_1),h(x_2)))
\end{align*}
but we don't have any control on $h$.

Edit2:
I think the answer is yes, from the inequalities
$$f(x_1, h(x_1))-L\cdot d(x_1,x_2)\leq f(x_2,h(x_1))\leq f(x_2,h(x_2))$$
and 
$$f(x_2,h(x_2))-L\cdot d(x_1,x_2)\leq f(x_1, h(x_2))\leq f(x_1, h(x_1))$$
which show that $g$ is $L$-Lipschitz. Is this correct?

Comment: what is the metric on $K\times K$?

Comment: The metric is given by $d\big((x,y),(x',y')\big):=d(x,x')+d(y,y')$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second approach is correct. I would write it like this: Fix $x_1, x_2 \in K$. For all $y \in K$ we have
$$
 f(x_1, y) \le f(x_2, y) + L d(x_1, x_2) \le g(x_2)  + L d(x_1, x_2)
$$
and therefore
$$
 g(x_1) \le g(x_2)  + L d(x_1, x_2) \, .
$$
The same holds with $x_1$ and $x_2$ exchanged:
$$
 g(x_2) \le g(x_1)  + L d(x_1, x_2) 
$$
and therefore
$$
|g(x_1) - g(x_2) | \le  L d(x_1, x_2)  \,.
$$